# Link to remote destroy is not updating div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I created a view that show all my invoices products and also created a link that remove an invoice product from a div and it will be updated so everytime that I remove everything will be in the same page.

Here is the table

```
invoices
  |id|  |name|
    1    ABC
    2    DEF

invoice_products
  |id|  |invoice_id|  |word|
    1      1           AAAA
    2      1           BBBB 
    3      2           CCCC   
    4      2           DDDD
```

Here is the controller:

```
def show
   @invoice= Invoice.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy_job
   @job = InvoiceProduct.find(params[:id])
   @invoice = @job.invoice
   @job.destroy()

   render :partial=>"finance_management/invoice/partials/new_subjects" }
end
```

Here is the model

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :invoice_products
end

class InvoiceProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

Here is the view: "show.html.erb"

```
<%= @invoice.id %>

<div id="table"%>
<% @invoice.invoice_products.each do |i| %>
   <%= i.name %>
   <%= i.word %>
   <%=link_to_remote(image_tag("image.png"), :update => "table",:url => { :controller=>'finance_management/invoice_product',:action => 'destroy_job',:id=>i.id }  )%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

The log:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `invoice_products' for nil:NilClass)
```

I created "delete_job.js.erb":

```
$('table').html("<%= j(render partial: 'finance_management/invoice/partials/new_subjects') %>");
```

But I got this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `invoice_products=' for nil:NilClass):
```

The problem is that is not updating the div seems because getting nil error

Somebody can help me please?

Comment: If I understand correcty you are trying to delete a invoice product from a invoice.

Comment: 1. You are sending the invoice.id and searching inside the invoiceproducts. 2.The name of the action delete_new_job vs destroy_job (or are you calling different controllers)? 3. You are rendering a partial, but I think that you are not setting the invoices object. Try to create a before_filter where you set the invoices array and it will do for all the actions.

Comment: Ok....I did 1, 2 but don't understand your 3 option ...can you check the code again please?

Comment: ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `invoice_products' for nil:NilClass) so the invoices array is not set. Try adding also "@invoices= Invoice.all" in your destroy method, just to see if it works

Comment: I tried but still not working

Comment: How about showing us the source code for your partial? I think Marko is right on track.

Comment: Ok I edited the post adding what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this you must do this:

The controller invoice_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @invoice= Invoice.find(params[:id])
  @products = InvoiceProduct.find(:all,:conditions=>['invoice_id = ?',params[:id] ])
end

def destroy_job
  @job = InvoiceProduct.find(params[:id])
  @obj_invoice = Invoice.find(@job.invoice_id)    
  @job.destroy
end
```

The view "invoice/show.html.erb"

```
<%= @invoice.id %>
<div id="table"%>
  <%= render :partial=>"invoice/partials/products" %>
</div>
```

Don't forget to create the partial view "invoice/partials/_products.erb" this will replace the div

```
 <% @products.each do |i| %>
    <%= i.name %>
    <%= i.word %>
   <%=link_to_remote(image_tag("image.png"),:url=>{:controller=>'invoice',:action => 'destroy_job',:id=>i.id})%>
 <% end %>
```

Finally create "invoice/destroy_job.rjs"

```
 page.replace_html 'table', :partial=>'invoice/partials/products'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file "destroy_job.js.erb" and place render method inside this file instead of calling it in controller:

```
$('YOUR_ID').html("<%= j(render partial: 'finance_management/invoice/partials/new_subjects') %>");
```

Comment: Ok I tried $('table').html("<%= j(render partial: 'finance_management/invoice/partials/new_subjects') %>"); and got  ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `invoice_products' for 1:Fixnum)

Comment: So the problem was not with rendering, but with the method 'invoice_product'. For which code line does it show this error?

Comment: When you render a partial, pass also @invoice object, like: `render :partial=>"finance_management/invoice/partials/new_subjects", :invoice=>@invoice` What is actually inside the partial 'new_subjects'?